# Why is a non-template class used as a nested member an incomplete type?

Tags: c++, class, templates

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 

template <class T>
class Enclosing {       
    private:    
       int x; 
    public:

    class Nested { 
        Enclosing A  ;
        public:  
        void NestedFun() { 
            cout<<this->A.x;   
        }        
    }; 
};


int main() 
{  
    Enclosing<int>::Nested temp;
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to declare an inner class Nested with Enclosing type. The code still runs well until I eliminate template, some errors appear, namely

```
field 'A' has incomplete type 'Enclosing'
```

and

```
forward declaration of 'class Enclosing'
```

Why this phenomenon happens???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `Enclosing` is a template, the definition of the type of `A` in `Nested` is not needed until `Enclosing` is instantiated, e.g. when you do:

```
Enclosing<int>::Nested temp;
```

At this point, since the instantiation is happening outside the definition of `Enclosing`, the definition of `Enclosing` is already complete, and so this compiles just fine.

---

On the other hand, if `Enclosing` is not a template, then as soon as the member variable `A` is parsed (while parsing the definition of `Enclosing`), the compiler complains that you are trying to use the definition of an incomplete type (which is true, since you are still inside the definition of `A`).

You can fix this by only declaring `Nested` inside `Enclosing`, and then defining it outside of `Enclosing`:

```
class Enclosing 
{
   class Nested;  // just declaration
   // ...
};  // Enclosing is defined now

class Enclosing::Nested 
{ 
    Enclosing A;  // now ok, because Enclosing definition is complete
    // ...
};
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Kjn7f5).

Comment: how about eliminating template and declare Enclosing *A instead of Enclosing A in Nested class. The code still works despite the incomplete construction of Enclosing

Comment: Yes, that works, because pointer types can be declared without needing a complete definition of the types they are pointing to. So `T t{};` doesn't work, but `T *t{};` works when `T` is incomplete.